# linking images on mouseover

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, mouseover

I had someone help me design my website a year or so ago, and need to fix something that looks to be incomplete.  I have an image that is replaced on mouseover of some text.  What I need is for the replaced image to be clickable to the same link that the text points to.  For example, a mouseover of the text "Portfolio" changes the image to one I have preloaded.  Clicking on the text "Portfolio" takes the user to the image gallery.  I would like to be able to click on the image to go to the same place as clicking on the text.  Here is the code that was implemented for me.

html

```
<div class="cmDirectory"><a onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[1],this.href)" href="http://www.example.com">Portfolio</a></div>
```

html for the initial photo that changes on mouseover

```
<a href="javascript:warp()"><img class="loader" src="/path/to/initialimage.jpg" name="targetimage" border="0"></a>
```

javascript

```
var myimages=new Array()
var gotolink="#"

function preloadimages(){
for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
myimages[i]=new Image()
myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]
}
}

preloadimages("/path/to/image1.jpg",
"/path/to/image2")

function changeimage(towhat,url){
if (document.images){
document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src
gotolink=url
}
}
function warp(){
window.location=gotolink
}
```

I'm a coding novice so please be specific with your answers.  It looks like I need to add something to the javascript to define the link for each photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
<a href="javascript:warp()"><img class="loader" src="/path/to/initialimage.jpg" name="targetimage" border="0"></a>
```

to this:

```
<a name="img_link" href="javascript:warp()"><img class="loader" src="/path/to/initialimage.jpg" name="targetimage" border="0"></a>
```

and in JavaScript replace this:

```
function changeimage(towhat,url){
if (document.images){
document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src
gotolink=url
}
```

with:

```
function changeimage(towhat,url){
if (document.images){
document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src
document.img_link.href=url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Using the changes you provided when I click the photo the url just goes from http://www.example.com/ to http://www.example.com/#  Is there something I need to do with the var gotolink="#" ? I'd like the link of the photo to be the same link as clicking the text that changes the photo on mouseover. Thanks

Comment: I tested what you said but found no problem(the links, the one with "/#" and the one without took me to the same page). I mean what does it matter if "/#" is appended to the end of a url as long as it takes you to the correct destination. But if the problem is something I didn't find then can you please either **elaborate** or provide a **jsfiddle**.

Comment: I hope I did this right... http://jsfiddle.net/c9b5L/   I would like the image on the right to be clickable to the same href as the text on the left. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is good and working you just need to add `onclick="warp()"` to the img tag, and just so that people get to know that the image is clickable you will have to add `style="cursor:pointer;"` also to the img tag.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with your suggestion, but it is still not working for me- http://jsfiddle.net/9YZ6L/2/  As I scroll down the gallery names on the left, the image changes, but clicking that image does not take me to the url that clicking the corresponding text does, which is what I would like to do. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake actually I don't know why but the name attribute sometimes dosen't work so just change `name="img_link"` to `id="img_link"` and in javascript change `document.img_link.href = url;` to `document.getElementById("img_link").href = url;`. This should work, it worked for me.